# Query optimization of an entity-value-attribute like data modeling

Tags: mysql, optimization, modeling, database-normalization, entity-attribute-value

I've been given a table of entities that will have three (and possibly more) character traits at any given time:

1. condition
2. soc
3. step

It's not important what these character traits are, except that they each have a large list of distinct values they may take, and that they may take only one at a time. Using these three character traits, I would like to search a table for items that should be displayed alongside the entity.

*E.g.: When the condition is x1 AND the soc is y1 or y2 AND the step is anything, display the item that says 'Hello'*

With the (entity-value-attribute) db modeling as shown below, the following query is behaving how I want. However, I suspect it could be more efficient if I weren't making several subqueries. Is it possible to rewrite this in a better way?

```
SELECT DISTINCT journey_items.id, 
   journey_items.category, 
   therapist_title, 
   therapist_body 
FROM   journey_items 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT id
    FROM journey_item_display_rules
    WHERE (`journey_item_id` = journey_items.id )
        AND (`category` = 'soc' AND `value` = 'any')
    )
AND EXISTS(SELECT id
    FROM journey_item_display_rules
    WHERE (`journey_item_id` = journey_items.id )
        AND (`category` = 'condition' AND `value` = '38')
        OR (`category` = 'condition' AND `value` = '25')
    )
AND EXISTS(SELECT id
    FROM journey_item_display_rules
    WHERE (`journey_item_id` = journey_items.id )
        AND (`category` = 'step' AND `value` = 'any')
    )
```

[image: item modeling]
[image: attribute modeling]

Comment: Welcome to the pain and agony of EAV.  See the tag I added.  And see my [_blog_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav).

Comment: @RickJames mostly expected this answer

Answer (score 2):

try using indexing in tables to optimize the query time.
Also you can use functions that will give you the resultants that you are using in where clause.